# "saw it work" vs. "saw it worked"

Tags: past-tense, indian-english

I read yahoo news on a daily basis and sometimes I find some mistakes in it. I post that part of the news here to make sure it is wrong (a typo mistake) or I do not understand it perfectly.

> News from Yahoo:
>
> “You say, please, do it for a short while; of course you’ll be back
>   up, let’s see how long it goes. Once he settled down to the idea and
>   saw **it work**, it was fine. When things went a bit wobbly at the 2003
>   World Cup, he was back up straight away,” Ganguly said.

As per my opinion:

> “You say, please, do it for a short while; of course you’ll be back
>   up, let’s see how long it goes. Once he settled down to the idea and
>   saw **it worked**, it was fine. When things went a bit wobbly at the 2003
>   World Cup, he was back up straight away,” Ganguly said.

Answer (score 5):

"He saw it work" and" he saw it worked" mean two different things. They are two different meanings of the verb "work".

- > He saw it work.

means he saw the idea in progress /as it was taking shape. The pronoun "it" is object of "saw".

- > He saw it worked.

means he realized the idea worked (i.e. was successful). We could rephrase the sentence that way:

> He saw that the idea worked.

The pronoun "it" is subject of "worked".

Comment: I beg to differ. "*I saw it work.*" means "*It worked and I saw it*." To express that you saw it in progress you say "*I saw it working.*" which means "*It was working and I saw it.*"

Comment: +1 @Graduate for assisting Laure! That's a good CommunityBuilder attitude.  But now we have two separate opinions which still leaves a bit of a deadlock. An even better comment will assist Laure in qualifying your answer as correct in a way to improve her answer. Could you perhaps further help by providing a reference as well? This is a Community Building function: if we're going to take the time to comment, we should strive to insure comments can be productively used.

Comment: @CoolHandLouis: My reference is the *Murphy's Grammar*. This book doesn't mention that you can say "*I saw it worked*," only that you can say "*I saw **that** it worked*." And there are no instances of any of these usages on *Google Ngram*, so we have to wait for native speaker's opinion, because I'm not one.

Comment: @Graduate: After see/hear (and other verbs) you can have either bare infinitive base of V-ing. It's difficult to catch the difference with work, but with a more concrete example like "I saw him cross the street" (→ I saw him leave one side of the street and get to the other side) and  "I saw him crossing the street"(→ I saw him at one point while crossing the street) it's easier to grasp I suppose, [more here](http://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/grammar/learnit/learnitv214.shtml).

Comment: @Graduate: The point I was making (apparently not clear) is that "work" has a different meaning whether the sentence reads "He saw it work" or "He saw it worked".  About "I saw it worked" and "I saw that it worked" it means exactly the same. When "that" is a conjunction it is often left out, it is quite common in an informal style. [More here](http://www.englishgrammar.org/omission/). I only expanded the sentence to show they have a different construction. "I saw it work" : "it" is object, "I saw it worked": "it" is subject of worked.

Comment: @Laure As per my opinion it should be "I saw that it worked" or "I saw it working". Maybe I am wrong! Thank you so much for your help but I am still a little bit confused about it.

Comment: @Graduate As per my opinion it should "I saw that it worked" or "I saw it working". Maybe I am wrong! Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: @user62015. As I said it depends what you want to say. And I do not find the quotation you give in your question clear enough on that point. When you say "I saw (that) it worked" it means the completed action  was successful. You don't have that idea of success at the end of an action when you use see+Ved (preterite) or see+Ving. The two constructions mean different things.

Comment: @Laure I agree with you and appreciate your help a lot. I pasted the paragraph from Yahoo.